# Lattice deformations of regular polytopes

Tags: polytopes, lattice-polytopes

It is trivial to see that the 24-cell, all hypercubes, and all polytopes with simplicial facets, can be deformed into lattice polytopes, and [this blog post](https://cp4space.hatsya.com/2013/09/22/rational-approximations-to-platonic-solids/) implies the same is true for the dodecahedron and great stellated dodecahedron. What about the twelve remaining regular polytopes?

Comment: By "deformed into lattice polytopes" I assume you mean finding a lattice polytope with the same combinatorial structure? Or do you also care about, say, convexity?

Comment: I mean finding a lattice polytope with the same combinatorial structure.